# Having trouble creating a scatter plot for my kmeans clustering data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to use kmeans clustering to perform some anomaly detection on a simple dataset.

I have some data in two variables.  x and x_ax.
Here is an example of the x data

```
array([[44360.125],
       [56385.958333333336],
       [61500.5],
       [61227.375],
       [60049.333333333336],
       [51396.916666666664],
       [49225.208333333336],
       [63211.083333333336],
       [64631.916666666664],
       [62546.708333333336],
       [62825.125],
```

The x_ax data are timestamp values...

```
array([Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-14 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-16 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-18 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-20 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-22 00:00:00'),
   Timestamp('2018-01-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-24 00:00:00'),
```

The idea is that the first value in the x data is related to the first element in the x_ax data.

I.e. 2018-01-01  --> 44360.125

I instantiated a Kmeans cluster instance:

```
 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(x)
 center = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

I then calculated the distance from the center for each point in x, sorted it and then extracted the top 5 greatest distances from the center (i.e., my potential anomalies).

```
distance = sqrt((x - center)**2)
order_index = argsort(distance, axis = 0)
indexes = order_index[-5:]
values = x[indexes]
```

I then attempted to plot this data as a scatter plot where dots marked in red were potential anomalies.

```
plt.plot(x_ax, x)
plt.scatter(indexes, values, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, I got a plot that looks like this:

[image]

The y-axis ticks seem to be correct, but why is the x-axis tick range going from 0 to 4000 in increments of 2000 for the first value, and then by 400 after that?

Also, why has my plot got all of the values in the upper right as a straight line except for one red dot in the lower left?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `plt.plot()` creates a line plot, thus the line in your upper right corner. What do you expect the x-axis to be?

Comment: Furthermore, if you are using Kmeans with one cluster, it is equivelent to just get the mean of your data i.e `center= np.mean(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)` and everything works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[44360.125],
              [56385.958333333336],
              [61500.5],
              [61227.375],
              [60049.333333333336],
              [51396.916666666664],
              [49225.208333333336],
              [63211.083333333336],
              [64631.916666666664],
              [62546.708333333336],
              [62825.125]])

x_ax = np.array([pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-11 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-13 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-14 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-15 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-16 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-17 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-18 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-19 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-20 00:00:00'), 
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-21 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-22 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-23 00:00:00'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2018-01-24 00:00:00')])

x_ax=x_ax[:11]
x_ax

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(x)
center = kmeans.cluster_centers_

distance = ((x - center)**2)**.5
order_index = np.argsort(distance, axis = 0)
indexes = order_index[-5:]
values = x[indexes]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) # Added
plt.plot(x_ax,x)
plt.scatter(x_ax[indexes], values, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the following code

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
x = np.array([[44360.125],
       [56385.958333333336],
       [61500.5],
       [61227.375],
       [60049.333333333336],
       [51396.916666666664],
       [49225.208333333336],
       [63211.083333333336],
       [64631.916666666664],
       [62546.708333333336],
       [62825.125]])


x_ax =np.array(['2018-01-01 00:00:00',  '2018-01-02 00:00:00',
    '2018-01-03 00:00:00',  '2018-01-04 00:00:00',
    '2018-01-05 00:00:00',  '2018-01-06 00:00:00',
    '2018-01-07 00:00:00',  '2018-01-08 00:00:00',
    '2018-01-09 00:00:00',  '2018-01-10 00:00:00',
    '2018-01-11 00:00:00'])

x_ax = np.array([p.replace(" 00:00:00","") for p in x_ax]) #Remove the 00:00:00
x_ax = [datetime.strptime(p,"%Y-%m-%d") for p in x_ax] #convert to datetime
x_ax = np.array([pd.Timestamp(p) for p in x_ax]) #Convert to Timestamp

x_ax
#array([Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
#       Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
#       Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'),
#       Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'),
#       Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'),
#       Timestamp('2018-01-11 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

#Fit kmeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(x)
center = kmeans.cluster_centers_

#Get outliers
distance = np.sqrt((x - center)**2)
order_index = np.argsort(distance, axis = 0)
indexes = order_index[-5:].flatten() #added .flatten()
values = x[indexes].flatten() #added .flatten()

#Plot it 
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,10))
plt.plot(x_ax,x)
plt.scatter(x_ax[indexes], values, color='r')
```

I get a plot with the correct x-axis
[image: plot]

**Note**

K-means works by repeatingly updating the mean of your clusters. When you have just one cluster, the `center` is equivalent to compute the mean of the data:

```
print(np.mean(x)) # 57941.84090909091
print(center) # array([[57941.84090909091]])
```